# Inverse inequality instead of Poincare inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $V_h = H^1$ and let $a(u_h,v_h) = (\nabla u_h, \nabla v_h)$ where $u_h,v_h \in V_h$.

Question: Can the inverse inequalities of type
$$||u_h||_{L_2}(\Omega) \leq Ch ||u_h||_{H_1(\Omega)},$$
be used to show coercivity of $a(u_h,v_h)$ on $V_h$:
$|a(u_h,u_h)| \geq ||u_h||^2_{H_1}$
? It is slightly counter-intuitive that such an inequality would work as it does not take any boundary conditions into account.

Answer (score 0):

To show coercivity for a bilinear form $a(u,v)$ where $u,v \in H^1$, one needs to show
$$
|a(u,u)| \geq \alpha \| u \|^2_{H^1}
$$
for some constant $\alpha$. If the bilinear form has a term similar to the left side of your inequality, then using by using the inequality we would be making it smaller by getting to the $H^1$ norm, which is the opposite of our goal. If the bilinear form has a term similar to the right side of your inequality, most often we could manipulate it differently since it may already be "close" to the form of $\alpha \| u \|^2_{H^1}$.

There may be cases where the inequality *could* be employed, but I'm not sure it would be necessary. Poincare, and other equalities of the type you have written, are often much more helpful in showing continuity of a bilinear form than it is for coercivity.

Comment: "If the bilinear form has a term similar to the right side of your inequality, most often we could manipulate it differently since it may already be "close" to the form of $\alpha||u||_{H_1}^2$."
@Will: The quoted sentence is the case I am interested in. I agree with what you wrote, but let's just for the sake of a discussion assume that we want to avoid using the Poincare inequality in this case. Would the inverse inequality work (and keep in mind that the space $V_h$ does not satisfy any Dirichlet boundary conditions)?

Comment: I'm not sure of any specific cases, and the only thing I can think of off the top of my head is a situation like
\begin{align*} 
|a(u,u)| = \int_{\Omega} (|u|^2 + 2|\nabla u|^2) \ d\Omega &= \int_{\Omega} (|u|^2 + |\nabla u|^2  + |\nabla u|^2) \ d\Omega \\ 
&= \| u \|_{H^1}^2 + \| \nabla u \|_{L^2}^2 \\ 
&\geq \| u \|_{L^2}^2  + \| \nabla u \|_{L^2}^2 \\ 
&\geq \| u \|_{H^1}^2
 \end{align*}
But one could also could have multiplied the first term in the integrand two at the start instead of using the inequality. I do wonder if there is a more interesting case somewhere.